# Git: pull from remote but keep local commits

Tags: git, github

For example: there is a local and remote repo with two files:

```
1.txt
2.txt
```

Developer #1 edits `1.txt` locally and commits the changes without pushing them to remote repo.

Later, developer #2 sends pull request with edited `2.txt`, and it gets merged in main remote repo.

My question is: how can developer #1 pull `2.txt` from remote repo, and keep changes to `1.txt`?

When I try to do this, extra commit is added after `1.txt` edit, so it looks like this:

- 14:00 `2.txt` commit from developer #2
- 15:00 `1.txt` commit from developer #1
- 16:00 `Merge branch "master" of https://github...` (`2.txt` commit again)

Thank you.

Comment: what's the problem?  you have the changes to both files already.  the extra commit is merging together developer 1 and developer 2's work.

Answer (score 7):

You should use

```
git pull --rebase
```

Your commit would be replayed after the other one this way, so its sha hash will change, but otherwise it will be the same. And this way you can avoid the extra "merge commit".

Comment: Furthermore, you can make `--rebase` rather than `--merge` the default behavior for a branch in the `.git/config` file.  And, also, you can make *that* setting the default for newly created/pulled branches via a global setting.

Comment: i'm wary of suggesting `--rebase` to anyone who doesn't intimately understand how it works — it's _very_ easy to get confused by conflicts and screw up your history (or, worse, your branch).

Comment: I guess in this situation the same could happen with merge as well. But you are right it isn't a 100% safe operation.